# Yarn install on mac m1 is giving Python executable "python2" in the PATH not found error

Tags: javascript, node.js, apple-m1, node-gyp, node-sass

**Im Trying to run a frontend project through yarn and i'm getting the following error when i do yarn install**

- node version 14.19.3
- yarn 1.22.18
- "node-sass": "^4.14.1",

```
yarn add v1.22.18
[1/5]   Resolving packages...
warning node-pre-gyp@0.17.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
[2/5]   Fetching packages...
[3/5]   Linking dependencies...
warning "react-apollo > @apollo/react-components@3.1.3" has unmet peer dependency "apollo-cache@^1.3.2".
warning " > react-formik-ui@3.0.8" has incorrect peer dependency "formik@^1.5.7".
warning "react-formik-ui > react-phonenr-input > react-country-flag@1.0.2" has unmet peer dependency "prop-types@^15.5.4".
warning " > babel-loader@8.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@>=2".
warning " > redoc@2.0.0-rc.31" has incorrect peer dependency "styled-components@^4.1.1".
warning "redoc > swagger2openapi > better-ajv-errors@0.6.7" has unmet peer dependency "ajv@4.11.8 - 6".
warning " > styled-components@5.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "react-is@>= 16.8.0".
warning " > eslint-config-airbnb@17.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0".
warning "eslint-config-airbnb > eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "eslint@^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0".
warning " > eslint-config-react-app@5.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "babel-eslint@10.x".
warning " > eslint-config-react-app@5.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-flowtype@3.x".
warning " > eslint-config-react-app@5.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-react-hooks@1.x".
[4/5]   Building fresh packages...
[-/13] ⠐ waiting...
[7/13] ⠐ node-sass
[-/13] ⠐ waiting...
[-/13] ⠐ waiting...
error /Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/node-sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node scripts/build.js
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/node-sass
Output:
Building: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.19.3/bin/node /Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.19.3/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@14.19.3 | darwin | arm64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /Users/suhasr/someproject/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21) {
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
gyp verb `which` failed }
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/Usersnode_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/Users/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/Users/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/Users/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /Users/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /Usersnode_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:192:21)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.19.3/bin/node" "/Usersnode_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v14.19.3
```